# Function that finds the specified distance from a point to any part of a rectangle

Tags: c++, computer-science, linear-algebra

Write a function that tests if a point is within a specified distance of any part of a filled rectangle.  The rectangle is specified by its center point, extents and rotation.

```
struct s_Vector
{
 float x;
 float y;
};

struct s_Rectangle
{
    s_Vector center;        // center of the rect in world space
    s_Vector localX;        // local space X direction vector, normalized
    s_Vector localY;        // local space Y direction vector, normalized
    float fExtentsX;        // distance from the rect center to the right edge
    float fExtentsY;        // distance from the rect center to the top edge
};
bool IsPointWithinDistOfRectangle(s_Rectangle & rect, s_Vector & point, float distance);
```

So I am so confused on how to use the localX and localy for the rotation of the triangle and then how to use that to fnd if the point is at a specified distance from the rectangle or not.

Comment: "The rectangle is specified by its center point, extents and rotation." where is rotation in the code? This question seems to be about geometry more than coding, once you know the maths, writing the code should be straightforward

Comment: hm ok, rotation seems to be given by `localX` and `localY` that somehow are the local coordinate system of the rectangle. Anyhow, what did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: It seems like `localX` and `localY` are unit vectors along the rectangle edges after applying rotation. In other words, for a non-rotated vector they are resp. `(1, 0)` and `(0, 1)`, while for a rotated rectangle they might be `(0.7431448254773942, 0.6691306063588582)` and `(-0.6691306063588582, 0.7431448254773942)`.

Comment: Isn't this basically a [signed distance field for rectangles](https://www.ronja-tutorials.com/2018/11/10/2d-sdf-basics.html#rectangle)?

Comment: 1) find the face of the rectangle that faces the point 2) calculate the distance from point to the line (not line segment but the full line) along this face 3) if the crossing point is on the rectangle you are done, if not closest point is one of the edges of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary rectangle, we can determine if a point is inside the rectangle as follows:

```
bool IsPointWithinRectangle(s_Rectangle & rect, s_Vector & point) {
    s_Vector dist = abs(point - rect.center);
    float dist_x = dot(dist, rect.localX);
    float dist_y = dot(dist, rect.localY);
    return dist_x <= rect.fExtentsX && dist_y <= rect.fExtentsY;
}
```

This uses the `dot` function to project the distance onto the local X and Y vectors. The extents of the rectangle are defined in terms of multiples of these local X and Y vectors, so we test against these extents.

If we now want to add the "within distance" constraint as well:

```
bool IsPointWithinDistOfRectangle(s_Rectangle & rect, s_Vector & point, float distance) {
    s_Vector dist = abs(point - rect.center);
    float dist_x = dot(dist, rect.localX) - rect.fExtentsX;
    float dist_y = dot(dist, rect.localY) - rect.fExtentsY;
    if (dist_x <= 0 && dist_y <= 0)
        return true; // In the rectangular area

    // If one of the two distances is negative (ie in the rectangle),
    // put it on the edge by setting distance to 0.
    dist_x = max(dist_x, 0);
    dist_y = max(dist_y, 0);

    // Finally, check if we are within a distance of the rectangle.
    // If the point is along one of the sides, one of dist_x and dist_y is 0,
    //   so compare the (squared) distance to `distance`.
    // Otherwise the point must be in a radius around the corner.
    return (dist_x * dist_x + dist_y * dist_y) <= distance * distance;
}
```

Comment: Quick Question what does the dot(dist, rect.localX) do exactly i have never seen that function before

Comment: The [scalar or dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) essentially projects one vector onto the other. Here I use it to express `dist` in terms of the local X and Y vectors

Comment: When i try to use the code is it ok to change the max(dist_x, 0) and max(dist_y, 0) an if statment that ask if(dist_x < 0) dist_x = 0;  would that yield the same result and also do i get errors on the abs part. btw thank you for your help it means alot

Comment: `std::max` is in the `<algorithm>` header. I am assuming the existence of an `abs` function that returns a vector `(abs(x), abs(y))`, but you can easily use `abs` on the separate components too.